# Default Password in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: system-installation

I just put Ubuntu 15.04 on a flash drive using pendrivelinux, and when attempting to install it on my computer, it asks for a username and password.  What is the default username and password?  I haven't been able to find it anywhere on the web.  Thanks!

Comment: There is no default , you get to choose a user name and password when you install.

Comment: I tried.  It's really weird, it expects you to log into the system somehow without even having installed it before.

Comment: Go ahead and reset .. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qGpvCZO2oOc

Comment: Try ubuntu as both username and password.  If that fails - recreate the usb. This sort of thing really shouldn't happen.  I installed ubuntu from different usbs on different machines - never had this issue

Comment: @Serg - the OP is running the installer, lol

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yes, i didn't miss that

Comment: it is not asking you to 'log in', it is asking you to 'create' log-in credentials that you can use form the next time you want to boot into Ubuntu. You can give any username and password you wish to have.

Comment: @Ron , I tried making up my own, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Ron He appears to be at the login screen (somehow).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) See step 12 of the top upvoted answer. There is no default password in the Ubuntu installer; unless you create one in the Ubuntu installer the default password is blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I used a PC with i5-CPU, 64bit, 8GB RAM , a NVIDIA GeForce GTX750 video card, and three monitors. After many hours of testing different situations, I took the basic equipment.

Only the computer with ONLY ONE MONITOR. And you cannot imagine, the installation worked normally. I could define new USER and new PW by myself. I installed Ubuntu 15.10 and then looked for drivers for GTX750, installed und updated the driver and connected three monitors .

Comment: Wow!  I had a GTX 750 too.  Very cool that you figured it out.  I switched to Linux Mint just because Ubuntu was giving me so much trouble.  Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If it looks like this:

[image]

It's asking you to chose your own password. Go for one at lwast 10 characters, (12 is better) that you don't use elsewhere, and has a mix of uppercase (`A-Z`), lowercase (`a-z`), numbers (`0-9`) and punctuation (`!"£$%^&*()-=_+{}[]:@~;'#<>?,./¬|\`).

If it looks like this:

[image]

The username is `ubuntu` and there is no password (just press enter when it asks).

---

<sup>Screenshots made with Oracle VM Virtualbox.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  It looks like the second image, and I tired ubuntu without a password, and it said I got it wrong.

Comment: @AnsonSavage Have you already installed ubuntu, or did you click Try Ubuntu?

Comment: I clicked the install ubuntu button.  It may be a problem with my outdated bios and current hard drive.  In 14.04, it had problems overwriting one of my partitions, so I went to 15.04, and got this far, but couldn't log in using any of the suggested username/password combinations.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, and you did a restart afterwards? That means you have installed ubuntu.

Comment: So login with the username and password you chose there, at the instalation?

Comment: The thing is, I didn't make a username and password yet.  I'll try puttung a new hard drive in and trying again.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Terminal
- `sudo su`
- `passwd`
- type desired password twice
- change with Ctrl+Alt+F1 to tty1
- Login