# Problem with 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I upgraded my laptop to 16.04 and now I can't get to the desktop login screen. I can only get to a black screen which asks me to type in a login and password. I also can't type anything in the password slot. What do I do??

Comment: For the second issue, see [Nothing shows up in the terminal when I type my password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/112069/nothing-shows-up-in-the-terminal-when-i-type-my-password)

Comment: Ok so what do i type in the login slot?

Comment: You type your username that you entered when you installed the system - that won't necessarily be the same as the 'fullname' that's normally displayed on the GUI login screen, it will usually be an all lower case name such as `jdelorme`

Comment: I think I'll have to get a new laptop because I've tired ever login name I think of and nothing works

Comment: That's extreme - you can always boot to [Recovery Mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and run the command `ls /home`; your username will almost certainly be the same as the name of your home directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm having a similar issue with Log-Ins and Passwords.

Have you tried using Ubuntu as the log-in and keeping the password blank like below:

- `username: ubuntu`
- `password:`

It's suggested in this answer: [Default Password in Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624324/default-password-in-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: Didn't work, what next?

Comment: what specifically happens? Can you post a screen shot or something @JDelorme?

Comment: How do you add a pic? I'm doing this off my mobile phone

Comment: Edit your post and there should be an option there @JDelorme

Comment: Can't do that either. My God is this a pain